# How To OverWrite Asset Folder Image In Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-assets

I have an images in asset folder , I want to share that images into another user like email , whats app etc .., Before that I want to draw some text on my share image form asset folder , and I want to overwrite into same asset folder then I want to share to the  user.

Comment: You **can't** modify the `assets` folder contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy image to sd card like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)
2. Modify/watermark your image like [this](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/image-processing-watermarking-on-the-fly/)
3. Share file like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Comment: While links are useful additions to an answer, a Stack Overflow answer needs to be useful without them, in case those links stop working.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify assets at runtime. You are welcome to copy data out of assets into the local filesystem, the modify your copy in the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for Your Quick Answer,  Is possible to write text while share the images

Comment: @parthi: There is nothing really built into Android for applying text to images, except when showing them to the user in the UI. However, you may be able to find some third-party libraries that offer this feature.

Comment: There is any link for achieve this

Comment: @parthi: I have no idea what "this" is.